# Firebase Firestore Listening to Changes in the Documents in a Collection

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I'm currently building an app and would like to both 1) listen to additions and removals of documents from a collection and 2) listen to any modifications to a document already existing in the collection.

Should I try doing this with a bunch of snapshot listeners, or via the use of some other method that I have no idea of?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It's not really possible to listen to only additions and removals to a collection.  You can listen to **all** of the documents in the entire collection, including additions, deletions, and updates.  All you have to do for that is simply query the entire collection using [snapshots()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/snapshots.html) on a [CollectionReference](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/CollectionReference-class.html), similar to what you see for queries in the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore#usage).